# Which adjective to use for a hour that has already started?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives

I am having a hard time with wording of a simple agreement (just as an exercise, not a real thing, of course).

I am trying to express that for each hour the person spends on some task, he will get $10. To be specific, if a person spends 1 hour and 1 minute on the task, he will get $20 in total.

Is there a single adjective I can use to write something like "For each *my-adjective-here* hour spent on the task, you will get $10"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is an adjective that could fit there, but you may write this as

> For each hour or part thereof spent on the task, you will get $10.

Comment: Thank you! Although not an adjective, it still fits into the text seamlessly - and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: The term I have most often heard is "...or fraction thereof..."